# Turn off mouse pad click noises

Tags: system-settings

Ive not been a linux user for that long and I unerstand that this may be a very noobie question but I really need to turn these clicks off.

I'm referring to a speaker click that is made when using the trackpad.  On certain events like expaniding a window ot such, a 'click' noise is played.

I dont know why but my tackpad registers phantom clicks, and the speaker clicks are driving me mad.

The pad is getting fixed next week and is useable but its like the speaker clicks are trying bully me... everytime I think that is going we... 'cli-cluk'...

Any help is appreciated as I dont have a lot of hair left :)

Comment: Your question implies the track pad is broken. Why are you trying to fix this if the broken pad is the issue? You also have not said what version of Ubuntu? What make and model is the track pad?